# In Notepad++, Is there a way to Find/Replace every instance of an XML attribute even when it has different values?

Tags: xml, replace, attributes, find

I have an attribute under the catalogSeqNumber tag called catalogSeqNumberValue (CSNV), and you can give it a number as its value, like this::

`<catalogSeqNumberValue="1">`

In this document, there are 20 instances of this attribute, numbered 1 through 20.

What I want to do is do a Find/Replace that will highlight all of them (including the value) so I can replace them all at once with the same value.

If it works, I would be able to replace all 20 instances of this tag with just one, so they will all have the same value.

I can't just do a Find/Replace for "1" because that matches other attributes that aren't related. I know I could just go in an replace them manually, but there are hundreds of them, and I'd like to be able to put all the XML files in a folder and use Notepad++ to replace them all in the folder.

Is this possible?

Comment: You seem to be confused as to whether this is an element or an attribute, your syntax is a mix of the two. But check if your chosen editor supports regular expressions. Alternatively, learn to do XML-specific editing in a much more powerful way using (for example) xmlstarlet or Saxon Gizmo.

Comment: Notepad++ has **XML Tools** plugin. It will allow you to run XSLT transformation for your task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a conceptual example via XSLT.

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <catalogSeqNumber catalogSeqNumberValue="1"/>
    <catalogSeqNumber catalogSeqNumberValue="10"/>
    <catalogSeqNumber catalogSeqNumberValue="18"/>
</root>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!--Identity Transform pattern-->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@catalogSeqNumberValue">
        <xsl:attribute name="catalogSeqNumberValue">
            <xsl:text>770</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<root>
  <catalogSeqNumber catalogSeqNumberValue="770"/>
  <catalogSeqNumber catalogSeqNumberValue="770"/>
  <catalogSeqNumber catalogSeqNumberValue="770"/>
</root>
```